# c++ pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

```
int a[5];

cout << &a[1] << " " << &a[0] << endl;
cout << (&a[1] - &a[0]);
```

In the above code, why is &a[1] - &a[0] equal to 1 and not 4? Shouldn't there be 4 bytes between these addresses since we have an int array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, pointer difference is in elements, not in bytes.

Comment: simple as that. @user974967: reading the book will be cheaper in the long run

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are incremented by the size of there type. Reason is because you want to point to the next item. So taking you example further.

```
int a[5];
int *ptr=&a[0];

// ptr is now pointing at first element.

ptr+3; // now its pointing at 3rd element.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it in bytes: (see it live https://ideone.com/CrL4z)

```
int a[5];

cout << (a+1) << " " << (a+0) << endl;
cout << (reinterpret_cast<char*>(a+1) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(a+0));
```